максимальный поток в потоковой сети

Решите, является ли следующее утверждение истинным или ложным. Если утверждение истинно, приведите краткое объяснение, а если ложно — приведите контрпример.
Пусть G — произвольная потоковая сеть с источником s, стоком t и положительной целочисленной пропускной способностью се для каждого ребра е. Если f — максимальный поток s-t в G, то fнасыщает каждое ребро, выходящее из s (то есть для всех ребер е, выходящих из s, выполняется условие f(е) = се).


Какие ваши мысли?

@MBo я думаю, что максимальный поток не обязательно насыщает все ребра, исходящие из источника, даже если он является максимальным по величине. Но правильная ли это мысль?

Правильная мысль

Верно. Теперь придумайте сеть, в которой такое происходит

@MBo подойдет ли такой граф? (s,u) = 10, (s,t) = 5, (u,t) = 5. Однако ребро (s,u) не полностью насыщено: по нему течет поток 5, в то время как его пропускная способность 10. Следовательно, можно увидеть, что максимальный поток не обязательно насыщает все ребра, исходящие из источника, даже если он является максимальным по величине

Да, вполне. Подойдёт любой пример, ,где сумма входящих в t дуг меньше суммы исходящих из s,  и ваш - один из самых простых
